# How do I successfully Deploy a Configuration Component for a Platform-Event Trigger to Override the Automated Process User?

Tags: salesforcedx, metadata-api, metadata, platform-event, mdapideploy

I am trying to override the Automated Process user with another user for a platform event.

This Salesforce documentation covers it:

[Configure the User and Batch Size for Your Platform Event Trigger](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.230.0.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_trigger_config.htm)

[PlatformEventSubscriberConfig](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.230.0.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_platformeventsubscriberconfig.htm)

In accordance with the second article, I'm trying to accomplish my goal by deploying a component containing configurations for my platform-event trigger (and I'm in API version 51.0), but every attempt I've made to deploy has failed.

Depending on how I go about it, either I achieve a successful deployment of 0 components, or it fails at the deployment of the one component.

In the latter case, this is the error message:

**An object 'RemoteTrxAcceptanceTriggerConfig' of type PlatformEventSubscriberConfig was named in package.xml, but was not found in zipped directory.**

I've tried both with workbench and sfdx.  I have a directory and a zip file like below in my sfdx project:

[image]

Besides workbench, I tried these commands:

```
sfdx force:mdapi:deploy -f metadata.zip -w -1

sfdx force:mdapi:deploy -d metadata -w -1
```

In all those attempts, the error is as I've shown above.

These are the files:

**RemoteTrxAcceptanceTriggerConfig**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PlatformEventSubscriberConfig xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <platformEventConsumer>RemoteTrxAcceptanceTrigger</platformEventConsumer>
    <batchSize>2000</batchSize>
    <masterLabel>RemoteTrxAcceptanceTriggerConfig</masterLabel>
    <user><USERNAME></user>
    <isProtected>false</isProtected>
</PlatformEventSubscriberConfig>
```

**package.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <name>PlatformEventSubscriberConfig</name>
        <members>RemoteTrxAcceptanceTriggerConfig</members>
    </types>
    <version>51.0</version>
</Package>
```

If I try with a wildcard in the members tag of package.xml, I get a successful deployment of 0 components.

I've tried no file extension for RemoteTrxAcceptanceTriggerConfig as well as:

- .*xml*
- .*component*
- .*xml-meta.xml*

I also tried accompanying *RemoteTrxAcceptanceTriggerConfig* with a separate *RemoteTrxAcceptanceTriggerConfig.xml-meta.xml* file, but I could only guess at what a correct one would look like, if at all applicable.

Comment: what command did you try in SFDX?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The below folder structure and file extensions worked for me

[image]

Notice I have prefixed the file with the name `.platformEventSubscriberConfig`

I used the command below

```
sfdx force:mdapi:deploy -d ./src --wait=-1 --json
```

Notice I don't have to deal with the zip files in this command. I am providing the directory relative path. In this case, it is `src` The CLI automatically takes care of it!

Since it's new metadata in `v51.0` the `source:retrieve` and `source:deploy` commands may not be supported

Comment: The documentation indicates the ability to deploy it, but maybe it's not ready yet since v51.0 is brand new.  I tried your suggestion.  It technically executes successfully, but deploys 0 components.

Comment: If you are on Spring 21 orgs, it did work fine for me! I can see in logs it went fine! Did you have the folder structure properly created as shown in the screenshot?

Answer (score 11):

This feature seems extremely finicky. I noticed that the XML metadata API deployment was NOT correctly populating the data (You can verify with the SOQL query below.) I managed to get it working *relatively consistently* with the following steps:

- Log in to Workbench -> REST Explorer
- Use the following POST endpoint: `/services/data/v51.0/tooling/sobjects/PlatformEventSubscriberConfig`  (See below if you get Duplicate ID error)
- JSON body should look like the following, replace names w/ desired names (doesn't need to correspond to any particular object or event name):

```
{
    "BatchSize": "2000",
    "DeveloperName":"YourNameTriggerConfig",
    "MasterLabel":"YourNameTriggerConfig",
    "PlatformEventConsumerId": "01qXXXXXXXXX",  <-- Apex Trigger ID
    "UserId": "005XXXXXXXXXX"  <-- Desired User ID
}
```

- **Then give it about 10 minutes**. Changes don't seem to apply immediately. May take longer if SF servers are under heavy load.
- If you get a `Duplicate Id` error, see **Note 2** below, you can use that query to manually delete these in your environment.

**Note 1**, if you do this in production, this configuration WILL flow down to Sandboxes and correctly update the User Id and Trigger Id automatically.

**Note 2**, you can query your PlatformEventSubscriberConfig in the dev console to make sure it is all configured correctly (or delete it if you get the `Duplicate ID` error in Workbench)

`Select id, MasterLabel, UserId, PlatformEventConsumerId FROM PlatformEventSubscriberConfig`

Comment: adding my observations: 
- It's possible to update records with a PATCH call to /services/data/v52.0/tooling/sobjects/PlatformEventSubscriberConfig/{ID}
also, as of Summer 21 v52:
- works only with apex triggers. We can't change batch size of Platform event Flows.
- PlatformEventSubscriberConfig doesn't affect test methods -  during test run all platform events will be processed in one transaction independent of BatchSize set in the org.

Comment: In order to get the PlatformEventSubscriberConfig to take effect, I found that I had to suspend the trigger's subscription (Setup | Develop | Platform Events | [Event Name] | Manage), then resume it.

Answer (score 0):

When working with the metadata source:

Folder Name: **P**latformEventSubscriberConfig**s**

(Case-sensitive and don't forget the capital 'P' at the beginning and lowercase 's' at the end) This deviates from the usual folder naming-conventions for the other metadata types.

Metadata Format Filename:  MyEventConfig.platformEventSubscriberConfig

Source Format FileName: MyEventConfig.platformEventSubscriberConfig-meta.xml

Package.xml

```
<types>
    <members>MyEventConfig</members>
    <name>PlatformEventSubscriberConfig</name>
</types>
```