# Using named/external credentials in an Apex trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, namedcredentials, externalcredentials

Context:
I have an Apex trigger for 'after insert' on EmailMessage.

The trigger invokes a future method containing a callout i.e. @future(callout=true)

This callout is a named credential which uses external credentials to add the auth headers.

Issue:
When I send an email into the system, I get an error:
System.CalloutException: We couldn't access the credential(s). You might not have the required permissions, or the external credential "Refresh_Token" might not exist.

I know the external credential exists and works because I can execute the same code for the callout in the developer console execute anonymous window.

I know I can fix my problem by hardcoding the API key into my Apex trigger but I would prefer not to do that because we don't want the keys in version control.

Does anyone know of a solution?
Many Thanks

Comment: Using a future from a trigger breaks if you are already in an async context. Read [this article](https://www.apexhours.com/governor-friendly-asynchronous-processing-from-triggers/) for an alternative approach. In using this approach, your callout will be performed by the `Automated Process` user (or another user [you nominate](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/357570/how-do-i-change-the-running-user-of-a-platform-event-trigger-handler)), not in the context of the user inserting the email message. That way permissions do not have to be given to the user creating the messages.

Comment: Fundamentally, this is very likely to be a permissions issue and switching user context here means you can still keep to minimum required access for the user, while the automation has the access is requires.

Comment: Hi Phil, sorry for the delayed response - I was taking annual leave over the last couple weeks! I've read the article you sent me and it looks promising. I'm going to attempt to implement the concepts mentioned this week and I will get back to you.
Many Thanks!

Comment: Success! the articles you linked have helped me solve the problem, many thanks!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Posting the answer here so others may reference this in the future.

Originally suggested by Phil W, the following articles solve the issue:

https://www.apexhours.com/governor-friendly-asynchronous-processing-from-triggers/
[How do I change the running user of a platform event trigger handler?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/357570/how-do-i-change-the-running-user-of-a-platform-event-trigger-handler)

Comment: Please try to reproduce the important parts of those articles here. Links tend to go dead over time, so including the important parts here means that this answer can still be useful to others after that happens.